# How to validate webform with JavaScript?

Tags: 7, webforms, forms, javascript

I've got a Webform for which I need additional calculations to hidden fields.

I've added a JavaScript file to the page by using `drupal_add_js`. And let that be the only part that works...

My **calculate.js** file looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("webform-client-form-80").onsubmit = function() {
  window.alert("Test!");
  document.getElementsByName("submitted[aantal18plus]")[0].value = 5;
};
```

Why don't I get an alert? And why doesn't the value of "**submitted[aantal18plus]**" get altered?
If I change "document.getElementById("webform-client-form-80").onsubmit" to "document.onload", **everything works**. But unfortunately, there isn't any data yet (tried with windows.alert("");)

**A bit more context:**
The form is a subcription form for a BBQ. I Have 16 fieldsets (for 16 persons at once) with 4 dropdown menus (for choice of meat). A LOT of fields, and a lot of different prices. I want to calculate things like 'total' and 'number of steaks'. I want to send those in the submission e-mail, so I created 12 hidden fields, and I do need to calculate those values on submit. 
I don't (necessary) need JQuery. At submit will do fine, 'cause the fields I'm altering are hidden.

Simply put: `onsubmit`, how on earth do I get it to work with javascript in drupal??

Comment: Damn, I hate phones...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a **custom module** for that:

1. webfv.info
2. webfv.module
3. webfv.js

Put all these files into a folder called **webfv**.

This is the **webfv.module** file:

```
<?php
function webfv_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'webform-client-form-80') {
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
    'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'webfv') . 'webfv.js', 
    'type' => 'file',
  );
}
}
```

And this is the **webfv.js** file:

```
    (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
      // Put your code here. //
      });
    }) (jQuery);
```

And of course, you should have a **webfv.info** file:

```
name = webfv
description = JavaScript Webform Validation
core = 7.x
files[] = webfv.module
```

Note: this is just one way of doing it, there are some other ways.

Comment: Same thing can also be implemented in a theme.

Comment: @othermachines yes sure. This is just one way of doing it, there are some other ways.

Comment: I really do appreciate the effort and you laid it out quite nicely. I've tried, but failed. I'm pretty new to modules, and even newer to JQuery.
Yet this seems like a very elaborate way to add a javascript file to a webform. I added one by adding a drupal_add_js line to the webform_node_80.tpl.php (I believe it was). The problem I'm facing is that "onload" works without hesitation, but "onsubmit" doesn't. Ever.
onload there isn't data to process yet, and onsubmit simply ignores me...

Comment: @herci  Alright, I get it now. Due to my inexperience it took me a couple of hours to figure it out.  But you were right! That is indeed the easiest way to get results. When I commented previously, I didn't understand the ways of the DOM structure; I didn't understand why....

Thanks for your input!